# why increasing worker numbers increase request time in gunicorn, wsgi, django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, gunicorn, wsgi

I am using gunicorn with wsgi and django for my rest beckend app. When I used gunicorn with one sync worker and send 20 same parallel requests, request execution time is about 100ms. When I increased number of workers to 4 and do the same thing execution time of request is four time bigger. I am using AWS and my app is in docker. How this could be possible? Should times be the same in both cases?

Comment: Can you give some more details? How are you making the parallel requests? Is the request execution time of 100ms the total time it takes for those 20 requests? What is the view doing (e.g. making a database call) to serve the request?

Comment: I have a script which in infinite loop sends same request. Than I start 20 scripts in same time. Time of 100ms is time from method initial request to finish_response on backend side. The View reads from database and return json object as response. When I start gunicorn with 4 sync workers i got execution time of 400ms. Maybe 4 workers is too much for AWS instance. I will try to reduce number of workers on 3 and 2 to see what is happening. Also I will try with worker_class gevent and eventlet.

Comment: Which AWS instances are you using? I found once the rule of thumb to use X+1 workers, where X is the number of (virtual) CPUs your instance has.